# display string in PHP with preg_match

Tags: php, string

I got the following string:

```
low|Low Resolution jpeg high|High Resolution jpeg eps|Eps
```

I would like to display in like :

```
<li>low</li><span>Low Resolution jpeg</span>
<li>high</li><span>High Resolution jpeg</span>
<li>eps</li><span>eps</span>
```

NB: The words cn be changed in the string, how can I use something like pregmacthe...

Comment: Really speaking you'd need to format the string so there's a delimiter between the entries as well - low | Low Resolution jpeg | high | High resolution jpeg - otherwise it'd be difficult to get the <li> element to wrap around the word

Comment: This isn't valid HTML.  Can't mix `<li>` and `<span>` like that.

Comment: ok, not valid html, just need my string to be implode/explode

Comment: ThiefMaster covered it in his answer - you must have missed the | from after the word jpeg. That's what confused me :) Glad you've got it sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you forgot a `|` in your string:

```
<?php
$str = 'low|Low Resolution jpeg|high|High Resolution jpeg|eps|Eps';
foreach(array_chunk(explode('|', $str), 2) as $chunk) {
    echo '<li>'.$chunk[0].'</li><span>'.$chunk[1]."</span>\n";
}
?>
```